# Como fazer uma instancia RDS via Inbound Rules/SecurityGroups receber acesso de uma instancia EC2?

Tags: amazon-aws

Para que minha instancia RDS receba acesso apenas da minha instancia EC2 via *Security Group*, eu crio a permissão MySQL no *Inbound Rules* e utilizo o *Private IP* da instancia EC2 ou o *CIDR* da minha *Subnet*?

Tanto um quanto o outro funciona perfeitamente. Qual deles utilizar e porque?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o CIDR da Subnet pois em caso de substituição da Instância EC2 como por exemplo em um caso de reparo a partir de uma Snapshot, você não precisará mudar a regra.